# Load balance between two Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set (VMSS)

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

**Our issue:**
The amount of time for provisioning a new instance takes a long time because of steps like certificate, encryption, domain join, TLS and Cipher changes,...

**Solution:**
In our use case, we end up to have two different VMSS for the purpose of deployment, re-imaging or blue green use case. Please note in our region (Azure Gov), we don't have access to low priority VMSS or Azure VM Spot to do pre-provisioning.

It only makes sense to have two different scales set behind a cloud-native load balancer (or private Traffic Manager - which is not available yet) to route request base on the VMSS prob readiness.

**Ask:** 
How can we have two Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set behind a load balancer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried this, but I dont see why this would not work with Standard Load Balancer (not basic, basic one is limited to 1 vmss, afair), if it doesnt - it should work with Application Gateway.

Comment: I feel the same, do you know how probing need to be configured to distribute the load to correct VMSS?

Comment: when I start to think about it, you cannot really do that if you want to have a single endpoint for both backends. unless you want to stick traffic manager in front of them. you can have something like `app.com/` to one backend and `app.com/backup` to another one

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually this is a private workload, we cannot use traffic manager since it doesn't have a private version

Comment: ok, according to the docs: `You can point a back-end pool to four types of backend members: a specific virtual machine, a virtual machine scale set, an IP address/FQDN, or an app service. Each back-end pool can point to multiple members of the same type.` so you can point same backend pool to 2 different load balancers. which would each be tied to a different vmss